# How to customize google chart with hyperlink in the label?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-visualization

I have different countries which I get with json and add to google charts. Each country has a link to a specific site. It works for me. But the name of the tooltip/label is a link. How can I remove the link in the tooltip and add the name of the country?
And how can change the country border color to white?
thx in advance.

**HTML**

```
<div id="visualization"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {
   var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country','Link',],
      ['Canada','http://www.google.ca'],
      ['Russia','http://www.bbc.com'],
      ['Australia','http://www.nytimes.com'],
   ]);

  var options = {
    colorAxis: {colors: 'white'},
    backgroundColor: '#81d4fa',
    datalessRegionColor: '#f8bbd0',
    defaultColor: 'black',
    displayMode:'regions',
    tooltip: {textStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}, trigger:'focus',isHtml: true},
    legend:'none',
    height:300,
    width:400
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', myClickHandler);
  chart.draw(data, options);

  function myClickHandler(){
    var link = data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0]['row'],1);
    // Change the current site
    location.href = link;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first,**  recommend *not using* `jsapi` to load the library

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the jsapi loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

this will *only* change the `load` statement, to...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawVisualization,
  packages:['geochart']
});
```

(the `callback` can be added to the `load` statement as well)

---

**next,**  according to the [data format for regions mode](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#regions-mode-format),

the second column should be a number (not a string / link)

but since the link is needed for the click handler, use a `DataView` to hide the column from the chart

^ this will fix the tooltip -- adding the name of the country instead of the link

the number column drives the shading of the country, according to the `colorAxis`

if no number is provided, as in the question, then `colorAxis` will have no effect

---

**last,** there are no standard options to control the country border

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawVisualization,
  packages:['geochart']
});

function drawVisualization() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country','Link',],
    ['Canada','http://www.google.ca'],
    ['Russia','http://www.bbc.com'],
    ['Australia','http://www.nytimes.com'],
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.hideColumns([1]);

  var options = {
    backgroundColor: '#81d4fa',
    datalessRegionColor: '#f8bbd0',
    defaultColor: 'black',
    displayMode: 'regions',
    tooltip: {textStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}, trigger:'focus',isHtml: true},
    legend: 'none',
    height:300,
    width:400
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', myClickHandler);
  chart.draw(view, options);

  function myClickHandler(){
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    if (selection.length > 0) {
      var link = data.getValue(selection[0].row, 1);
      window.open(link, '_blank');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="visualization"></div>
```