# Hyperlinks on Google GeoChart with Markers

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, maps, pygooglechart

I do have this on my website running:

```js
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawVisualization,
  packages:['geochart']
});

function drawVisualization() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country','Link',],
    ['United States','https://proyectoviajero.com/destinos/america-del-norte/guia-viaje-estados-unidos/'],
        ['Japan','https://www.proyectoviajero.com'],
    ['Saint Lucia','https://www.proyectoviajero.com'],
    ['Peru','https://proyectoviajero.com/destinos/america-del-sur/guia-viaje-peru/'],
        ['Chile','https://proyectoviajero.com/destinos/america-del-sur/guia-viaje-chile/'],
        ['Argentina','https://proyectoviajero.com/destinos/america-del-sur/guia-viaje-argentina/'],
        ['Bolivia','https://proyectoviajero.com/destinos/america-del-sur/guia-viaje-bolivia/'],
        ['Brazil','https://proyectoviajero.com/destinos/america-del-sur/guia-viaje-brasil/'],
        ['Spain','https://proyectoviajero.com/destinos/europa/guia-viaje-espana/'],
        ['Portugal','https://www.proyectoviajero.com'],
        ['Italy','https://www.proyectoviajero.com'],
        ['Belgium','https://www.proyectoviajero.com'],
        ['France','https://www.proyectoviajero.com'],
        ['Germany','https://www.proyectoviajero.com'],
        ['United Kingdom','https://www.proyectoviajero.com'],
        ['Poland','https://www.proyectoviajero.com'],
        ['Ukraine','https://www.proyectoviajero.com'],
        ['Hungary','https://proyectoviajero.com/destinos/europa/guia-viaje-hungria/'],
        ['Czechia','https://www.proyectoviajero.com'],
        ['Turkey','https://www.proyectoviajero.com'],
        ['Morocco','https://proyectoviajero.com/destinos/africa/guia-viaje-marruecos/'],
        ['Western Sahara','https://proyectoviajero.com/destinos/africa/guia-viaje-marruecos/'],
        ['Tunisia','https://www.proyectoviajero.com'],
        ['Switzerland','https://www.proyectoviajero.com'],
        ['Finland','https://www.proyectoviajero.com'],
        ['Estonia','https://proyectoviajero.com/destinos/europa/guia-viaje-estonia/'],
        ['Iceland','https://proyectoviajero.com/destinos/europa/guia-viaje-islandia/'],
        ['Philippines','https://www.proyectoviajero.com'],
        ['Greece','https://www.proyectoviajero.com'],
        ['Bulgary','https://www.proyectoviajero.com'],
        ['Croatia','https://www.proyectoviajero.com'],
        ['Brunei','https://proyectoviajero.com/destinos/asia/guia-viaje-brunei/'],
        ['Qatar','https://proyectoviajero.com/destinos/asia/guia-viaje-qatar/'],
        ['United Arab Emirates','https://proyectoviajero.com/destinos/asia/guia-viaje-emiratos-arabes/'],
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.hideColumns([1]);

  var options = {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    datalessRegionColor: '#F5F5F5',
    defaultColor: '#ffc17f',
    displayMode: 'regions',
    tooltip: {textStyle: {color: '#222222'}, trigger:'focus',isHtml: true},
    legend: 'none',
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', myClickHandler);
  chart.draw(view, options);

  function myClickHandler(){
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    if (selection.length > 0) {
      var link = data.getValue(selection[0].row, 1);
      window.open(link, '_blank');
    }
  }
}
  </script>
```

I am trying to plot a country (i.e. Spain) with two markers (i.e Madrid and Barcelona as a red circle) with hyperlinks to an external webpage.

But I do not know how to modify it. Basically I am trying to reach the same result in [THIS](https://www.nomadicmatt.com/travel-guides/spain-travel-tips/) webpage.

Can anyone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: check this answer --> [How to customize google chart with hyperlink in the label?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40933696/5090771)

Comment: Thanks! but still not being a solution as I want CLICKABLE MARKERS on the map, which should be country focused....